# How to run a Python program directly?

Tags: python

How to run a Python program directly?

I have created a *.py* file (say, *mnik.py*) in gedit. It runs smoothly in terminal.

Command goes

```
python3 mnik.py
```

But whenever I click on the file it is opened with gedit. I cannot run it directly by clicking.

What to do?

Comment: Related: [How do I run Python code as a script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/590410/3712)

Comment: Typing `python3` on the command line is not the proper way to run a Python script. You should be invoking it as `./mnik.py` or if it is in your `PATH` you could simply type `mnik.py`. Apart from that, there is an excellent answer below detailing the rest you need to do.

Comment: @kasperd Typing `python3` on the command line with an argument is an excellent way to run python scripts. It is in fact the easiest way to run a program that requires a terminal and arguments (like many of my own scripts, but also programs like `mercurial`, `sphinx`). Care to explain why what I have been doing for 20+ years is not the proper way?

Comment: @Anthon A correctly written script has a `#!` line at the start specifying which interpreter to use. When you type the interpreter name on the command line you might not notice if you made a mistake in creating the script. It also means there is a risk you mistakenly type the incorrect interpreter, which is a risk there is no reason to take. Finally it is shorter to type `./mnik.py` than to type `python3 mnik.py`.

Comment: @kasperd A correct written Python script (or program)  doesn't have to have a shebang line. If it doesn't it is still a Python script in every way. That script just cannot be executed by from the Linux shells in the short-hand form you seem to prefer.  There are also environments that don't require Python scripts to have a shebang line at all and allow them to start the script by double clicking.

Comment: @Anthon The kernel will refuse to execute a script without the `#!` line. If you type `strace ./mnik.py` and the script has no `#!` line, you will see the error. The error code is `ENOEXEC`, which translates to `Exec format error`. There are workarounds to run a badly formatted script, but you should not rely on workarounds, when you have the option to do things right.

Comment: @Anthon For testing I just created a "Python script" with only the single line `print "Hello world"`. This may work just fine if you **always** use the same workaround. But sooner or later somebody will not know about your preferred workaround, and will try to execute the script the way a script is intended to be executed. It happens to be the case that `bash` has its own workaround, which is different from yours. And the error I get is this: `Warning: unknown mime-type for "Hello world" -- using "application/octet-stream"` `Error: no such file "Hello world"`

Comment: @kasperd What the kernel needs in order for a Python script to run using `./scriptname` doesn't validate your claim that running a script from the commandline by using `python3`. There are different ways of running python scripts and doing `python3 ./mnik.py` is also a proper way of doing things, it is just different (and at least you get python3 that way and not python2 as is more  likely with the most the answers so far)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38806/discussion-between-kasperd-and-anthon).

Comment: Using <language> <script> is a *totally* valid and accepted way to run a script. Suggesting it is bad practice should be frowned on.

Comment: @JacobVlijm If all the problems I have pointed out with that approach cannot convince you, then the only thing that could possibly convince you is getting bitten by one of those problems yourself. I can assure there is no way you are going to convince me. Because I know the practice you suggest is more typing, and more error prone.

Comment: @kasperd I do not have the intention to convince you :). Use whatever you like. Just need to mention to others that it is *your* choice.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's two things needed.

1. A script must have `#!` line telling the OS which interpreter to use. In your case your very *first* line in the code must be `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
2. You need to open file manager , go to Edit -> Preferences -> Behavior, and select what to do with executable files

   [image]

   3. Finally , make sure your file itself actually has executable permissions set. In terminal you can do `chmod +x /path/to/script.py` and in GUI, right click on the file and alter its Properties -> Permissions

   [image]

   [image]

Note about shebang line

The very first line is called shebang line and must start with `#!` ; whatever comes next is the name of the interpreter that will read your code. In case you are using `python3` you could use either `#!/usr/bin/python3` or  `#!/usr/bin/env python3` for portability. If you are not using code that will be specific to python version - just use `#!/usr/bin/env python`

#### Note on the script output:

If your script prints output to console, it will need to have terminal window, or alternatively use GUI dialogs such as `zenity`.  Prefer using `Run in Terminal` option if you want to see the code. If you want the script to do something without seeing console output - use `Run` option.

[image]

In addition, if you have command line parameters , such as `sys.argv[1]` in the script , you can't set them unless you have terminal window open.

Comment: @PriyadarshiPaul That's the same as `Files` program on the launcher . In windows-speak that would be file explorer or `My Computer`

Comment: @PriyadarshiPaul it's `nautilus` in the Terminal

Comment: @grooveplex  You probably meant that comment for Priyadarshi  :)

Comment: @Serg I just can't get the meaning of this line " in GUI, right click on the file and alter its Properties -> Permissions"

Comment: @Serg Now there is two options 
1. run 
2. run as terminal 
2nd option is working , but 1st is not . What to do?

Comment: @PriyadarshiPaul 1st option is working. But it's doing so in background. You basically need to have terminal output or  some form of gui dialog to see output.

Comment: @Serg related: [Should I put `#!` (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31954823/4279)

Comment: @Serg ok now for the run window stay in desktop , I have imported time module and using time.sleep(sec). But It is not working.

Comment: @PriyadarshiPaul well , can you post the script source to paste.ubuntu.com and link it here ? Or better yet, create a new question on the site, because this particular question i'd say is solved. But please post it to paste.ubuntu.com first

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python` will invoke Python2 on most Ubuntu systems. Although you can make a Python script written for Python3 compatible with Python2, I would not assume that the OP has done so. `#!/usr/bin/env python3` seems a more appropriate shebang

Comment: I have to agree with @Anthon that the `#!` line should say `python3` rather than just `python`. The OP explicitly mentioned `python3` in the question. Simply specifying `python` without a version number means the script author has to ensure the script works all relevant versions, which today means `python2` and `python3`, but in the future it may include `python4` compatibility as well.

Comment: @kasperd didn't i address that already at the ens of the answer ?

Comment: @Serg The paragraph near the end is fine. But the `#!` line shown at the top of your answer says just `python`. Since the question said `python3`, I think your first example should have said `python3` as well. The problem is that specifying just `python` as interpreter name without a version number de facto means `python2`. And it is not easy to change that. Leaving out the version number while typing the script is one character less of typing. That's a very minor advantage, which does not outweigh the drawbacks of having to ensure your code works with both `python2` and `python3`.

Comment: @Serg And even if you are writing code which works with both `python2` and `python3`, what advantages are there to leaving out the version number in the `#!` line rather than explicitly specifying one of the two versions? It's one character less typing, but that's not much of an advantage. I don't know of any other advantages from only typing `python`. If there are any, then please enlighten me.

Comment: @kasperd There is one disadvantage: Arch Linux. python is python3. :/

Comment: And why are we bringing up Arch Linux here ?  Maybe I'll come across as a bit mean , but we're talking Ubuntu here. On Ubuntu by default python is linked to python2.7 If you're developing software ,  you probably should be aware of what links where, if you use something other than your OS's default version, then explicitly specify so.   Sure , we can cater to each individual question , but for crying out loud - if you code , then do it right .

Comment: @JonathanHartley That should not be the case. `/usr/bin/python` should always by Python 2.

Comment: You know what, yep I'm wrong. I upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 and yes, just as you say, '/usr/bin/python' is still python2. I retract.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the location of the program to execute your code on the first line and you then need to set the script to run as an executable by changing its permissions. This assumes you're launching your applications from terminal or another script.

**Find your Python installation**

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

**Add the programs location to the top line of your program with a `#!` in front**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Python code goes here....
```

**Set the Python script to have execution rights**

```
$ chmod 700 test.py
```

**Now you can run the script directly**

```
$ ./test.py
```

**Code listing for test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "test"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run this program without typing `python3 mnik.py` you have to make the script executable and make sure that `python3` is used to run it.

The first you can do by running

```
 chmod +x mnik.py
```

the second you can do by adding as the first line of a script a shebang line *that invokes python3*. On all the Ubuntu systems I have worked with that came with python3, you can get python3 by adding this line at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

After those two changes you can type `/path/to/mnik.py`, `./mnik.py` or just `mnik.py` (the latter requires the script to be in your PATH).

If you make these changes you might also want to consider renaming `mnik.py` to `mnik`, that is common practice with Python packages with commands that are published on PyPI.

Comment: ok , Any of these now does not work

Comment: What is "ok"? What does "these" refer to?

Comment: It's saying 

** usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
**

Comment: There is at least a `/` missing at the front there. Please explain what "It" is in you comment. Is it the bash shell? Is it windows Command.com? From what are you invoking the program and with what commandline syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround if you don't want to bother with setting your script as an executable, adding comments to your code or selecting to run from the terminal every time you run it.

Go to `~/.local/share/applications`, create a new `.desktop` file there. Call it something like `python-run.desktop`. Paste the following into it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Run Python Script
Comment=Python Interpreter
Exec=gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'python3 %f;echo "$(tput setaf 1)Program terminated.\nPress enter to exit...$(tput sgr 0)"; read'
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/python3.6.xpm
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
StartupNotify=true
NoDisplay=true
```

This is mostly copied from the `.desktop` file of python interpreter itself. The difference is when you open it, it runs a new instance of the terminal line with the command: `python3 %f;echo "$(tput setaf 1)Program terminated.\nPress enter to exit...$(tput sgr 0)"; read'`, which runs the script (`%f` is apparently the file's path), then pauses on exit.

Then go to nautilus, right click on the script, go to *Properties → Open With* and select *Run Python Script*, the "Application" we just created. Now when you double click, it should run the script from the terminal.

It's a pretty good workaround but I have found 2 problems with it:

1. It doesn't work with scripts that have a space in their name.
2. It opens a separate terminal window which is pretty annoying. For some reason, I couldn't get it to work by just setting `Exec=python3 %f`, it kept giving me an end of file exception whenever the program tried to get input. No idea why.

Comment: I think escaping the spaces in the filename would solve the first problem. And the second problem is because the [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) of your script is not connected to any tty (or ```pty```(pseudo tty) in graphical terminals ).If you want to get the user input interactively in a non-graphical (text-based) way , opening a terminal or at least using the current one is necessary.