# Run Python utility from shortcut

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, gnome-classic, python-2.7, tftp

I installed [TFTPGUI](https://code.google.com/archive/p/tftpgui/downloads). The only way launch program GUI is run command in console,

`python tftpgui.py`

Is there way or method launch it from desktop shortcut? I tried create shortcut, placed it on desktop, but there is no Python in programs that listed to select for opening with. Gnome Flashback, Ubuntu 14.04. 
I tried shell script, but it does not launch anything.

```
#! /usr/bin/python 
python tftpgui.py
```

Comment: Does this answer help? http://askubuntu.com/a/281138/320386

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can I run a python script in ubuntu 12.04's from the graphical interface](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281134/can-i-run-a-python-script-in-ubuntu-12-04s-from-the-graphical-interface)

Comment: No, shell script not launch tftpgui.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by setting proper option for an "Executable Text Files".  The location is bit tricky:

**Applications > Accessories > Files > Location options > Preferences > Behavior tab > "Executable Text Files" -> choose "Ask each time".**

Click **Run** when you need launch application.